# Apache Airflow issue with training Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, airflow

I deployed apache airflow 1.10.9 on docker with postgres 13 and I've built an ML pipeline for data collection - model training - evaluation etc.

All the tasks are running normally but when the pipeline arrives to the task where I train my model the task is stuck on running state indefinitely

From the logs I've noticed that is stuck on model .fit method of Keras on the first epoch.

I've run the python script of model training from inside the airflow container without any issues so the environment is not the problem.

My guess is that it has something to do with airflow cached logs or memory.

I've tried cleaning the logs but it didn't work.

If anyone has any workaround or any idea I would appreciate it.